# SQL How to change value With all References

Tags: sql, reference, updates

Is there an easier way to change a single value in a row together with its Reference , and that Reference's reference, Instead of backtracking through 20 tables to find the beginning of it all?

Links to Answers
--[On Cascade](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.sqls.doc/sqls118.htm) (Thanks Javier)

```
ALTER TABLE catalog DROP CONSTRAINT aa

ALTER TABLE catalog ADD CONSTRAINT
   (FOREIGN KEY (stock_num, manu_code) REFERENCES stock
   ON DELETE CASCADE CONSTRAINT ab)
```

Comment: An example of the structure of the tables, or code to update the tables?

Comment: Structure. Javier has already given the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to define the reference as "ON UPDATE CASCADE"?